# What's wrong with my wp database query?

Tags: categories

```
$cats = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT term_id, term_taxonomy_id, taxonomy, parent 
FROM wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy 
WHERE term_id = term_taxonomy_id 
AND parent = 1
AND taxonomy = "category"', ARRAY_A);
```

I'm trying to get all the categories in my database that are children of the category of ID 1, but it's not working. What's wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason why you can't use WordPress API?

```
 $cats = get_categories(array(
          'child_of'=>1
       ));
```

See [Codex here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).